# Downloading file from wp-admin folder

Tags: admin

How do I download file.csv?
'/var/www/vhosts/example.com/box/wp-admin/file.csv'

Tried like this and a bunch of other ways but no luck

`echo '<a href="example.com/box/wp-admin/file.csv" download>Download</a>';`
`echo '<a href="/var/www/vhosts/example.com/box/wp-admin/file.csv" download>Download</a>';`

Comment: You are failing, because you are trying to access restricted areas of a WordPress installation, and the `.htaccess` is prohibiting you. Why not you are using cPanel only?

Comment: Damn ... I hate failing :)

Comment: Can't i allow a certain user access to the wp-admin folder?

Comment: Elaborate on "no luck"? What _is_ happening? The rule of a thumb is that WordPress isn't involved in serving _any_ static file.

Comment: When I try to download, it says No file. The download starts just like any other. How would you recommend I do this. I'm actually going to email the file, but I want to know how I can download a file also.